# How to download all images from a folder

Tags: php, html, apache

I am displaying the images through the Apache server. 
When I click on each image it should open `download.php?fiel=file_name.jpg` and download the image to the system.

**This is the code for Image Display**

```
  <?php
 $files = glob("Image/"."*.*");
 for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
$num = $files[$i];
echo $num."<br>";
echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="Here should be image" width="256" height="192" >'."<br/>";
}
?>
```

**I used the following code to download the Image** (i.e download.php file).

```
 <?php
 $file = $_GET['file'];
  header("Content-type: image");
 header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= ".$file."");
 readfile($file);
 ?>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I hope that there are some security checks in your download.php file to prevent an attacker from reading any file on your file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this? :

```
<?php
$files = glob("Image/"."*.*");
$countFiles = count($files); //Don't do calculations in your loop, this is really slow

for ($i=0; $i<$countFiles; $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];

    echo '<a href="download.php?file=' . $files[$i] . '"><img src="'.$num.'" alt="Here should be image" width="256" height="192" ></a><br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Is `count()` an expensive calculation? Doesn't it just get the size from the array header? And unless your loop is executing millions of times, it's not likely to make a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (glob("Image/*.*") as $file) {
  echo "<a href='download.php?file=$file'>$file<br>\n";
  echo "<img src='$file' alt='Here should be image' width='256' height='192'/><br>\n</a>";
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean foreach instead of for? However, doing calculations in a loop can be really slow since it's evaluated every single time.

Comment: @DillenMeijboom Thanks for the correction. But what calculations am I doing in my loop?

Comment: When you do foreach(glob("Image/*.*") as $file) the glob function will be called for every entry. When you use something like this: foreach($files as $file) and $files contains glob("Image/*.*") then the glob function will be called only once which is a lot faster.

Comment: @DillenMeijboom I don't think that's true, but I'll do a test to check.

Comment: @DillenMeijboom My test confirmed that a function call in the array parameter to `foreach` is executed only once.

Comment: Okay, maybe the PHP compiler got that fixed! When I used PHP (couple of years ago) this was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download all images in a single folder I would suggest you to archive your images with tools like zip or something similar. You can zip files in php on the fly. To iterate over all files in a directory take a look at [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)) as $file) {
    var_dump($file);
}
```